# PDO query stop loop - Php

Tags: php, html, linux, pdo

so i trying to use some query at pdo , but only the first select show results , the second select dont show the results , only show " Selecione "

look my code below

```
    <?php
    $con1 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db','root','passdb');
    $con1->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sqlimpressora = $con1->query("SELECT * FROM impressoras");
    ?>

     <html>
      <body>
         <form>
              <select name="impressora" class="form-control">
                    <option value="selecione">Selecione...</option>
                    <?php while($prod = $sqlimpressora->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $prod['nome'] ?>"><?php   echo $prod['nome'] ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>

                </select>
          <select name="impressora" class="form-control">
                    <option value="selecione">Selecione...</option>
                    <?php while($prod2 = $sqlimpressora->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $prod2['nome'] ?>"><?php echo $prod2['nome'] ?></option>
          <?php } ?>

                            </select>

          </form>

         </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: Both your `<select>`'s bear the same name attribute. So if you intend on using this later on somewhere, only one will take effect and pull the results from it.

Comment: can i use the result from query at two select ?

Comment: give the `<select>`'s different name attributes; start with that.

Comment: i have change the names of select's , but still without work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each call to `$sqlimpressora->fetch()` will move the cursor to the next record in the result set. So when your first while loop finished it moved the cursor to the end of the result set and thus another `fetch()` call fetched nothing.

One possible solution is to fetch the records into an array and use `foreach` to iterate through it:

```
$rows = $sqlimpressora->fetchAll();

foreach ($rows as $prod) {}

foreach ($rows as $prod) {}
```

Comment: I posted my answer 1 min earlier than the accepted answer :(

Comment: you too is great ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `->fetch` twice, use [->fetchAll](http://php.net/pdostatement.fetchAll) and loop over the result.

```
$sqlimpressora = $con1->query("SELECT * FROM impressoras");
$result = $sqlimpressora->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $prod) {

     // <select > .....
}
```